# Overset and vertical align

Tags: overset

I'm using the `\overset` command and I would like to vertically align the overset values

[image: Unaligned overset values]

Comment: See if `\vphantom` can help.

Answer (score 3):

We can add a vertical phantom, but we must be careful to preserve the correct spacing. I'd use a new macro `\varoverset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varoverset}[2]{\binrel@{#2}%
  \binrel@@{\mathop{\vphantom{M}{#2}}\limits^{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\overset{0}{\neg} Aa \overset{0}{\lor}
(\overset{0}{Mcc} \overset{0}{\leftrightarrow} \overset{1}{Mba})
\\
\varoverset{0}{\neg} Aa \varoverset{0}{\lor}
(\varoverset{0}{\mathit{Mcc}} \varoverset{0}{\leftrightarrow} \varoverset{1}{\mathit{Mba}})
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\binrel@`/`\binrel@@` construction is inherited from the original definition of `\overset` and takes care of spacing. The second argument of `\varoverset` is put in braces in order to make a `\mathord` out of it, otherwise the spacing with the `\vphantom` would be in general wrong.

Note also that if `Mcc` and `Mba` are multi-letter variables you should better put them into a `\mathit` (as I did in the second formula).

**EDIT** For full control you can define a new length to be used in general, and an optional parameter to change it locally.

```
\newlength{\varoversetheight}
\settoheight{\varoversetheight}{M}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varoverset}[3][\varoversetheight]{\binrel@{#3}%
  \binrel@@{\mathop{\vrule width\z@ height#1{#3}}\limits^{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use a stack to create the overset. (I also steal campa's `\binrel@` trick, +1).  The advantage here is that the overset position is tune-able, either through the use of an optional argument on a case-by-case basis, or by resetting the default `\oversetnorm` value.  This is handy if the height of the objects are unusually tall, for example, if hatted.

The MWE shows this default `\oversetnorm` value adjusted for the 2nd row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\newcommand\oversetnorm{.7\normalbaselineskip}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myoverset[3][\oversetnorm]{%
  \binrel@{#3}\binrel@@{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{#1}{#3}{\scriptstyle#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\myoverset{0}{\neg} Aa \myoverset{0}{\lor}
(\myoverset{0}{\mathit{Mcc}} \myoverset{0}{\leftrightarrow} \myoverset{1}{\mathit{Mba}})
\]
\renewcommand\oversetnorm{11pt}
\[
\myoverset{0}{\neg} Aa \myoverset{0}{\lor}
(\myoverset{0}{\mathit{\hat M\!cc}} \myoverset{0}{\leftrightarrow} \myoverset{1}{\mathit{\hat M\!ba}})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooh, I was just adding the optional parameter too `:-)`

Comment: LOL, @campa.  The war of measure-countermeasure continues unabated!  Or else like high-stakes poker:  I'll see your `\binrel@` and raise you one `\oversetnorm`.

Comment: Oh well, as long as the escalation leads to nicer TeX code it's fine `:-D`