# Underset minuscule m to \(\models\) and \(\vdash\)?

Tags: overset

Given the following MWE, based upon the answer by Steven B. Segletes to the question [Overset and vertical align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611123/overset-and-vertical-align), may one obtain corresponding (\models) and (\vdash) with *underset* minuscule m?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\newcommand\oversetnorm{.4\normalbaselineskip}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myoverset[3][\oversetnorm]{%
    \binrel@{#3}\binrel@@{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{%
                \stackengine{#1}{#3}{\scriptstyle#2}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    
    \(\myoverset{\textsc{m}}{\models\,}\), \(\myoverset{\textsc{m}}{\vdash\,}\) 
    
        
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something similar to the following.

I redefined `\models` as I can't really stand the default rendering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
% redefine \models to be similar to \vdash
\renewcommand{\models}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\models@\relax}}
\newcommand{\models@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \mspace{-1.3mu}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\vdash$}
  \resizebox{\width}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1|$}}%
  \mspace{-3.8mu}%
  \nonscript\mspace{0.8mu}%
  \raisebox{0.25\height}{\resizebox{\wd\z@}{\height}{$\m@th#1=$}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\inset}[1]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\inset@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\inset@}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\m@th#1\mspace{3mu}_{#2}$}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mmodels}{\inset{\scriptscriptstyle\textnormal{\scshape m}}\models}
\newcommand{\mvdash}{\inset{\scriptscriptstyle\textnormal{\scshape m}}\vdash}

\begin{document}

\(\models\vdash\)
\quad\(\scriptstyle\models\vdash\scriptscriptstyle\models\vdash\)

\(\mmodels\mvdash\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code complies with me.

Comment: @Sapiens Yes, sorry: I copied the wrong thing.

Comment: I appreciate your redefinition of \models

Comment: @Sapiens I did a small change

Comment: As you will understand, I want the underset minuscule m to not extend below the vertical bar of \vdash or \models. May that be done?

Comment: @Sapiens That would require a very tiny M

Comment: You are right, it was not precisely what I wanted. But if I erase \scshape and use \newcommand{\mmodels}{\inset{\textnormal{m}}\models}
\newcommand{\mvdash}{\inset{\textnormal{m}}\vdash},\(\mmodels\) does not look good.

Comment: I resolved it by using \newcommand{\mmodels}{\inset{\textnormal{\tiny m}}\models}
\newcommand{\mvdash}{\inset{\textnormal{\tiny m}}\vdash}